# Setting up SQL Connection String for DotNetNuke in shared host environment

Tags: connection-string, dotnetnuke

I'm setting up a DotNetNuke application on a shared hosting environment and I'm really new to the ASP.Net world. In a shared environment, do I have a web.config file? or does my host have to set up my connection string for me?

I have access to the IIS through my host's control panel.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

I've visited the DotNetNuke Wiki and it's given me guidance on the connection string itself, but I can't seem to locate the web.config file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DotNetNuke will setup the connection string for you during the install process.

**When you select "SQL Server Database", it will ask you for:**

1. authentication method (Windows Auth, SQL Authentication),
2. location of the server (Example: IP Address)
3. Database Name (Empty Database needs to be pre-created)
4. Username and Password (if you selected SQL Authentication)

Before proceeding to the next step, the installer will make sure it can access the database given the information that you provided.

If it succeeds, and the next step proceeds, that means the connection string was already setup for you.

**So where do you get your information for steps 1 - 4?**

1. Basically, your hosting provider should have this information for you. There will be a preferred authentication method for step 1 above. It is probably SQL Authentication.
2. Your host should tell you where your SQL Server is located -- they should give you a hostname or IP Address for the SQL Server.
3. For step 3, There should be some method for you to create databases -- probably using a web interface or, if you're lucky, SSMS.
4. Finally, they should have provided you `sa` login credentials for Step 4 -- but it's best if you can create your own credentials and provide them access to only your DNN database for this step.

Comment: Thank you. If there was a change in the location/name/username/password 'after' the initial setup, can I change the web.config file to reflect that somehow? Or do I need the host to do that?

Comment: I don't think it's possible to change it from within DNN, because I don't think it would be possible to display the host settings page without a connection to a valid DB. Sorry I can't help here!

Comment: Well, I wouldn't say 'can't help'! You've provided some great info for me. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

In a shared host environment you will have your own web.config file, with most hosts you should be able to at least access it via ftp if not some fancier control panel.

In a shared hosting environment some web.config settings will be dictated by the host and ignored in your own web.config.  For example the host will likely force your site to run under medium trust no matter how you configure your own web.config.